# Watching Objects with Sockets in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, sockets, vuejs2

I'm using Sockets to receive data from a remote server.

I'm using the following an app Vue component:

```
let app = {
 name: 'app',
 data: {
  dataStore: {}
 },
 mounted () {
  var vm = this;
  socket.on('data-receive', (data) => { //data = {user: 'myUser' value: 45}
   vm.dataStore[data.user] = data.value // also tried Vue.set(vm.dataStore, data.user, data.value)
   console.log(vm.dataStore)
  })
 }
```

The weird thing is that the console logs `dataStore` properly as expected. Even the Vue Developer Tools show the proper data stored in `dataStore`. But, the `dataStore` is rendered as `{}` on the following HTML

```
<app>
{{dataStore}}
</app>
```

And here's what's rendered:

`{}`

Is there anyway to force re-render?

Comment: why don't you reference `dataStore` as `this.dataStore` ?

Comment: wiil that make a difference?

Comment: in `console.log` I think yes

Comment: let me check...

Comment: Ok then `console.log` prints `dataStore` correctly then ?

Comment: yeah.. it does. Even the vue dev tools chrome extension shows the data. Only issue with render.

Comment: In my opinion, since you are performing an asynchronous job, you'd better define a custom **Watcher** : [https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: But, how is console.log() showing up correctly

Comment: it is changed but doesn't trigger the change on render, so either define a watcher or use `https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate` to force update

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```
mounted () {
  var vm = this;
  socket.on('data-receive', (data) => { 
   Vue.set(vm.dataStore, 'user', data.user)   // or vm.$set(...)
   Vue.set(vm.dataStore, 'value', data. value)
   console.log(vm.dataStore)
  })
}
```

As described in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the data object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive

One can add reactive properties to a nested object using the `Vue.set(object, key, value)` method:

### Edited:

As suggested in comment, as the code is in sockets, probably this is happening outside vue instance and using [forceUpdate](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) renders updated variable in HTML.

Comment: I tried using `Vue.set()` but it failed. I had no render even then

Comment: What if I want to do this: will this work? `Vue.set(vm.dataStore, data.user, data.value)`? Because I have many users to track

Comment: This is not working.. The `conole.log` is working as it was before, but I still have issues only with render. Something to force render?

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed is `app` a vue component, why I am asking is [data must be a function](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function) for vue component.

Comment: Yeah. It is a component. And I have returned data as a function in my actual code.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed can you add all your relevant code as it is, there my be some other caveat/error, which might help.

Comment: Sure. In couple of minutes.

Comment: Using `Vue.$forceUpdate()` fixed the problem.